# How to get uniques IDs and totals with Pivot Table Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have this table in columns A to F

```
    A     |      B       |     C     |     D      |        E         |   F     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File1      |              |           |            |                  |
Record     |  ID          |  ABKs     |  MNKs      |  Date            |  Seg
NewRecord  |  972567676   |  34305    |  72358     |  3/4/2019 22:13  |  21
NewRecord  |  685206308   |  8198     |  27174     |  3/4/2019 22:16  |  61
NewRecord  |  300264531   |  393064   |  10093118  |  3/4/2019 22:18  |  238
NewRecord  |  300264531   |  431153   |  10055124  |  3/4/2019 22:22  |  232
NewRecord  |  300264531   |  394506   |  10091831  |  3/4/2019 22:25  |  239
File2      |              |           |            |                  |  
Record     |  ID          |  ABKs     |  MNKs      |  Date            |  Seg
NewRecord  |  300264531   |  494676   |  9992073   |  3/4/2019 22:29  |  307
NewRecord  |  300264531   |  480117   |  10005787  |  3/4/2019 22:35  |  326
NewRecord  |  300264531   |  500751   |  9986284   |  3/4/2019 22:53  |  74
NewRecord  |  300264531   |  174754   |  10312153  |  3/4/2019 22:54  |  19
File3      |              |           |            |                  |  
Record     |  ID          |  ABKs     |  MNKs      |  Date            |  Seg
NewRecord  |  725372898   |  734660   |  9751476   |  3/4/2019 23:04  |  79
NewRecord  |  725372898   |  1307025  |  9178944   |  3/4/2019 23:05  |  256
NewRecord  |  725372898   |  530935   |  9955441   |  3/4/2019 23:18  |  41
NewRecord  |  725372898   |  564462   |  9921311   |  3/4/2019 23:19  |  713
File4      |              |           |            |                  |  
Record     |  ID          |  ABKs     |  MNKs      |  Date            |  Seg
NewRecord  |  941774677   |  441381   |  10044548  |  3/4/2019 23:46  |  1196
NewRecord  |  941774677   |  336354   |  7138685   |  3/5/2019 0:06   |  839
File5      |              |           |            |                  |  
Record     |  ID          |  ABKs     |  MNKs      |  Date            |  Seg
NewRecord  |  1303422672  |  1947830  |  8538344   |  3/5/2019 0:30   |  126
NewRecord  |  1303422672  |  939494   |  2130082   |  3/5/2019 0:33   |  107
```

I want to create a pivot table that shows me the data as mentionen in **Expected Pivot Table format** 
but I'm currently getting the output as shown in **Current Pivot Table output**
[image: enter link description here]

I've set the pivot table as shown below.
[image: enter link description here]

Is possible to get the table desired with pivot table? and what I need to do for such result?

Attached sample excel file

[image: Sample1.xslx]

Answer (score 0):

Just drag PivotField/Column {Date} from "values" to "Rows" in Pivot
It will affect your column sequence.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Dragging date to "Rows" changes the table layout. I fix the issue leaving date on "values" and setting the field to show the `Min` value. It's still not sorted as desired output that is, sort the IDs in order of appearance in source table. I don't know how to do that.